# Limit involving quotient of logarithms

Tags: limits, logarithms

Let $a, b>0$. There are conditions on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{a(\ln bx)^{\frac{5}{4}}}{(\alpha^{\frac{1}{\beta}}\ln x^{\frac{5}{4}})^\beta}= \infty?
\end{equation}

I am convinced that it is not possible, but I cannot justify it.

Comment: I'm unsure that I did it right.  It looks like L'Hopital's rule kicks in.  When I took the derivative of the numerator and denominator separately, I got that the value of $\alpha$ is irrelevant (assuming that it is positive), and that there is a condition on $\beta$.  I suggest you try L'Hopital's rule, and even if it doesn't solve the problem, you will have **shown your work**.  This will allow mathSE reviewers to provide an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With
\begin{eqnarray}
 \frac{a(\ln bx)^{\frac{5}{4}}}{(\alpha^{\frac{1}{\beta}}\ln x^{\frac{5}{4}})^\beta}
&=&c\frac{(\ln bx)^\frac{5}{4}}{(\ln x)^\beta},~~c=\frac{a}{\alpha(5/4)^\beta}
\end{eqnarray}
using L'Hôpital's rule
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(\ln bx)^\frac{5}{4}}{(\ln x)^\beta} &=&
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{5}{4}(\ln bx)^\frac{1}{4}}{\beta(\ln x)^{\beta-1}}
\end{eqnarray}
it follows that the term diverges for $\beta\le1$. For $\beta>1$ we use L'Hôpital's rule again
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{5}{4}(\ln bx)^\frac{1}{4}}{\beta(\ln x)^{\beta-1}}&=&
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{5}{16}(\ln bx)^{-\frac{3}{4}}}{\beta(\beta-1)(\ln x)^{\beta-2}}.
\end{eqnarray}
Thus, for $\beta\ge2$ the limit is 0. For $1<\beta<2$ we obtain
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{5}{16}(\ln x)^{2-\beta}}{\beta(\beta-1)(\ln b + \ln x)^{\frac{3}{4}}}&=&
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{5}{16}(\ln x)^{2-\beta}}{\beta(\beta-1)(\ln x)^\frac{3}{4}(\ln b/\ln x + 1)^{\frac{3}{4}}}\\
&=&
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{5}{16}(\ln x)^{2-\beta}}{\beta(\beta-1)(\ln x)^\frac{3}{4}}\\
&=&
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{5}{16}}{\beta(\beta-1)}(\ln x)^{2-\beta - \frac{3}{4}}
\end{eqnarray}
with convergence for $2-\beta - \frac{3}{4}\le 0$ or $\frac{5}{4}\le \beta$.

Comment: Thanks, Its_me. You helped me a lot!

Comment: Was your proof premature, re OP had not yet shown any work?